# Generating Chisel Module IO Interface From a List

Tags: chisel

I would like to generate a Module IO interface from a spec I have stored in a scala variable.

I would like to produce this class definition:

```
class AddIfc extends Module {
   val io = IO(new Bundle {
     val a = Input(UInt(8.W))
     val b = Input(UInt(8.W))
     val o = Output(UInt(8.W))
   })
}
```

from something like a list of tuples:

```
List( ("a", "in", 8), ("b", "in", 8), ("o", "out", 8))
```

I can imagine building an AST and evaluating it using some of the reflection capabilities in scala. Has anyone done this and have an example to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Record](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/api/index.html#chisel3.core.Record) (the parent class of Bundle). They're a bit more advanced because you have to implement elements (rather than reflection doing it for you in Bundle), and you have to implement cloneType.

There is an [example in the Chisel tests](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3/blob/master/src/test/scala/chiselTests/RecordSpec.scala#L14).